# Minimax (with alpha beta pruning): when to store the solution?

Tags: minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I have implemented a version of the [minimax algorithm with alpha/beta pruning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning), for a [connect four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four) game. When using minimax, I would like to save the best AI column to play for in a dictionary called `solution` (so that, I can also save other information if needed).
So my pseudo code looks like this:

```
function alphabeta(node, depth, α, β, maximizingPlayer, solution) is
    if depth = 0 or node is a terminal node then
        return the heuristic value of node
    
    value = None
    if maximizingPlayer then # AI is playing
        value := −∞
        for each child of node do
            value_new := alphabeta(child, depth − 1, α, β, FALSE)
            if value_new > value then
                value = value_new
                solution.update({'best_column': child_node_move})
            if value ≥ β then
                break (* β cutoff *)
            α := max(α, value)
    else
        value := +∞
        for each child of node do
            value := min(value, alphabeta(child, depth − 1, α, β, TRUE))
            if value ≤ α then
                break (* α cutoff *)
            β := min(β, value)

    return value
```

where `child_node_move` is a move being tested from a new child node (e.g. each child node is a connect four state, with a move being tested for best move).

Now, I have noticed that the algorithm doesn't quite work when I store values in `solution` and I don't filter on the depth. Indeed, the algorithm will work at depth 1 but not when I increase the depth parameter.

The only way I managed the algorithm to work, is by modifying the update of `solution` only when the depth is at 0. For example, If the initial depth is four, I replace part of the above code with:

```
if value_new > value then
    value = value_new
    if depth == 4: # only store for the root level => this works
        solution.update({'best_column': child_node_move})
```

So my question is two-fold:

- Am I supposed to store the solution only at the root level? If so, why? I don't really understand why this is working actually, and not the other way around.
- Should I also store solutions when the MIN player is playing? To me it makes no sense. Also, what is the MIN player minimizing? His own score, or the MAX score?

Edit: here is my code

```
def minimax(self, board: np.ndarray, depth: int, alpha: float, beta: float, is_max_player: bool, solution) -> float:

    assert alpha < beta
    
    sy, sx = board.shape
        
    # When the depth limit of the search is exceeded,
    # score the node as if it were a leaf
    # The heuristic value is a score measuring the favorability of the node for the maximizing player.
    if depth == 0 or self.is_last_move(board) or self.is_winning_move(board):
        return self.score(board)
    
    if is_max_player:
        value = -np.inf
        for k in range(0, sx):
            if 0 in board[:, k]:
                b = ConnectN.play(board, k, True)
                value_new = self.minimax(b, depth - 1, alpha, beta, (not is_max_player), solution)
                
                if value_new > value:  # maximize value
                    value = value_new
                    solution.update({'col': k, 'depth': depth, 'score': value,'is_max_player': is_max_player})

                if value >= beta:  # beta pruning
                    break

                alpha = max(alpha, value)  # no fail-soft
    else:
        value = np.inf
        for k in range(0, sx):
            if 0 in board[:, k]:
                b = ConnectN.play(board, k, False)
                value_new = self.minimax(b, depth - 1, alpha, beta, (not is_max_player), solution)
        
                if value_new < value:  # minimize value
                    value = value_new
                    # solution.update({'col': k, 'depth': depth, 'score': value,'is_max_player': is_max_player})

                if value <= alpha:  # alpha pruning
                    break

                beta = min(beta, value)  # no fail-soft 

    return value
```

`board` is a `numpy.ndarray` with shape (sy=6, sx=7). Function is called like this:

```
solution = {}
score = self.minimax(c4, 4, alpha=-np.inf, beta=+np.inf, is_max_player=True, solution=solution)
best_move = solution['col']
```

The score function is pretty basic (pseudo code):

```
  initial score = 0

  for every sets of four slots (horizontal, vertical, both diagonals)
  do

      if AI connects four chessmen: score = Infinity
      elif AI connects three chessmen and one empty slot: score += 300 
      elif AI connects two chessmen and two empty slots: score += 200 

      if HUMAN connects three chessmen and one empty slot: score -=500 
      if HUMAN connects four chessmen: score = -Infinity                
   
  return score
```

Comment: It is hard to know the answers to your questions without knowing a bit more. Why would you like to store the solution each time you find a better move? What is the purpose of this data gathering?

Comment: @eligolf actually, I just wanted to provide stats in the algorithm (like number of alpha/beta prunings, depth, etc). Also, gathering information was made to try debug the algorithm. However, it's not supposed to change the way the algorithm behave. So I really don't know why I does not work in the end.

Comment: As I always recommend, go for Negamax instead which will clean up your code a lot and make it a lot easier to implement other things without duplicate code and general headache :) Try to get it working with Negamax, and just a the normal best_move saving technique first. Then you could look into saving more data

Comment: @eligolf thanks, actually I have tried with negamax and have the same error xD Maybe an heuristic issue? I'll see if I can post a message with negamax instead...

Comment: Negamax is the same idea, just compressed and without lots of duplicate code. It should be easier to implement other things with it, rather than minimax :) Please do, and @ me when you have it up and I will try and have a look at it